# Mapbox Lighting API on 3D Layer

Tags: 3d, mapbox-gl-js

Lighting API is new to me. How do I control the light intensity of the 3d building (*yellow area*)? A layer was inserted already.

```
map.addLayer({
                'id': 'room-extrusion',
                'type': 'fill-extrusion',
                'source': 'floorplan',
                'paint': {
                    'fill-extrusion-color': ['get', 'color'],
                    'fill-extrusion-height': ['get', 'height'],
                    'fill-extrusion-base': ['get', 'base_height'],
                    'fill-extrusion-opacity': 0.5
              }
            });
```

[image]